# Translucent Glass Pane over java.awt.Panel

Tags: java, swing, awt, jogl, jzy3d

Hi have a `Swing` User Interface composed by 4 different plots (extensions of `javax.swing.JPanel`). One of these plots is built using `jzy3d 1.0.0` library and returns a component of type `CanvasNewtAwt` (extension of `java.awt.Panel`). So that I have a `java.awt.Panel` inside my usual `javax.Swing.Panel`.

The problem is that when I load the glass pane, since it is an instance of `javax.swing.JPanel`, the `AWT` component remain on top of it.

Is there any way to avoid this? 
If I create a new glass pane which extends `java.awt.Panel` I'm able to cover all of the plots but not able to make the glass pane translucent. So If I fix the translucency problem (using a `swing` panel), I'm not able to cover the `awt` component, but If I use an `awt` panel, I have all my frame covered (very unpleasant result). Big deal :)

> **NOTE**: I know that older versions of `jzy3d` allow to create `Swing` plots, but `Swing`classes are **deprecated** in newer versions, since they are full of bugs, and replaced with `Newt` components.

Comment: com.jogamp.newt.awt.NewtCanvasAWT extends java.awt.Canvas. Do you reproduce this behaviour under several operating systems?

Comment: I have the chance to try only on Windows10. Anyway, `org.jzy3d.plot3d.rendering.canvas.CanvasNewtAwt` extends `java.awt.Panel` ([API](http://doc.jzy3d.org/javadoc/0.9.1/jzy3d-api/org/jzy3d/plot3d/rendering/canvas/CanvasNewtAwt.html)). I solved by hiding the `org.jzy3d.chart.Chart` when `Swing` glass pane is displayed and drawing a snapshot in place of it using the `paint()` method of the `javax.swing.JPanel` which contains the chart. But I was wondering if there is a better way to handle these situations.

Comment: I don't contradict you, I know that org.jzy3d.plot3d.rendering.canvas.CanvasNewtAwt which is a java.awt.Panel wraps a com.jogamp.newt.awt.NewtCanvasAWT which is a java.awt.Canvas. I'll let you know if I find a better solution.